# How To Copy Webview Text in EditText?

Tags: android, text, webview, android-edittext, copy

Hi How To Copy Webview Text in EditText?
I use bellow code but it not work fine.
where is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

```
wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        wv.loadUrl("http://appsupportirandroid.blogfa.com/");
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ed.setText(wv.toString());
```

Comment: what do need? html?

Comment: In fact i want to part of webview text that start with !$#@ and ended with *$#@ and show sected text in dialog. for example !$#@ reza gharbavi *$#@ show reza gharbavi in dialog.